# Background process terminates after the deployment group phase ended

Tags: azure-devops, sh, agent

I'm using Azure DevOps (formerly known VSTS) to run a script in a Linux Machine (specifically CentOS machine).

I have an inline script task that runs the process on background, but after the deployment group phase has ended. The process that was created is also terminated.

Below is the sample script I've written

### Using screen:

```
screen -dm ping localhost
```

Result:

- Release is successful
- Process id can't be found in target server
- Shows that the screen is `dead`

### Using nohup + redirection + ampersand

```
nohup ping localhost 2>&1 &
```

Result:

- The task didn't finished, it's stuck.

Is this the default behavior of VSTS Deployment Agents?

Comment: `screen` and `nohup` are both meant to keep a process running on a machine _which keeps running_ after the user has logged out again or lost connection.  They cannot survive a shutdown of the machine.  Are you sure in your case that the machine (vm probably) really keeps running after your disconnect?

Comment: @Alfe, yes. I ran it manually in via PuTTY, closed the terminal. Connected to VM again using different username, I can still see the PID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the default behavior. VSTS will close all the processes that launched during the execution when the build/deployment is finished.

Comment: thanks for confirming. Do we have an official document about this?

Comment: @FreddieFabregas I didn't find any document, but you can refer to the source code here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/ab40f0b1a5be5206c2c193c77628ce8d79c8abb0/src/Agent.Worker/JobRunner.cs And you could queue your build or deployment with "process.clean" variable set to "false" so that the launched process won't be killed. But since this is not documented yet, I'm not sure if it will change in the future.